# Connecting to a reverse proxy via a reverse proxy

Tags: apache-http-server, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up a web radio environment called AzuraCast. I'm using a provided docker installation script which sets up multiple containers:

- a web server container
- a "stations" container
- an nginx proxy which is supposed to work as a so-called reverse proxy to access the web container
- a mariadb container
- and some other stuff which is not of interest for now.

On my server I am running an apache2 docker container (`php:apache`) which I have set up reverse proxies on to access other docker containers I have installed (e.g. nextcloud, airsonic, ...):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *.443>

# ...

    ProxyPass /audio http://airsonic:4040/audio
    ProxyPassReverse /audio http://airsonic:4040/audio

    ProxyPass /nextcloud http://nextcloud
    ProxyPassReverse /audio http://nextcloud

    ProxyPass /git http://git:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /git http://git:3000

# ...
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now, when I want to access the web container of the AzuraCast installation, on my server I only need to access http://localhost:8298 (8298 being the HTTP port I am using since 80 is already being used by my apache2 container). However, if I want to create a reverse proxy for the AzuraCast web frontend I would assume I just had to add

```
    # since the container-internal HTTP port from the nginx proxy is still 80, there's no need to specify a port here
    ProxyPass /radio http://azuracast_nginx_proxy_1
    ProxyPassReverse /radio http://azuracast_nginx_proxy_1
```

However, when I'm now trying to access the AzuraCast backend via my reverse proxy at https://my.domain/radio, I am able to access the page but none of the pictures or links work which makes me wonder if there's something like a context path needed or if maybe the proxy pass hasn't been configured correctly. here's what the backend looks like:

[image: Backend with missing images etc.]

And here is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: Correct backend design]

**Now my question is:**

Am I supposed to set something like an environment variable? Neither links nor pictures work because the backend proxy does not add the `/radio` path to the links provided by the website so the path which is supposed to look like this `https://my.domain/radio/login` only looks like this `https://my.domain/login`.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Neither links nor pictures work because the backend proxy does not add the `/radio` path to the links provided by the website[.]

The simplest answer may be to try using a separate subdomain (a virtual host in Apache or server block in Nginx, respectively) rather than e.g. `/radio`. So, for example, in Apache something like:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName radio.example.com
        # ServerAlias radio.localhost
        # DocumentRoot "/www/unneeded"

        ProxyPass / http://azuracast_nginx_proxy_1/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://azuracast_nginx_proxy_1/

        # ...

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Let's Encrypt**

Note that for Let's Encrypt HTTP verification, you'll likely need a separate, non-forwarded subdomain on port 80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName radio.example.com
    # ServerAlias radio.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/www/http-auth-folder"

</VirtualHost>
```

You should be able to use an index page with a meta refresh of ex. 0 at the root of e.g. `/www/http-auth-folder` if you wish to automatically redirect browsers to the HTTPS version of your site without interfering with Let's Encrypt queries.

Comment: that sounds like a reasonable thing to do, I'll give that a try.

Comment: So I tried this and added a subdomain entry on my domain manager `radio.example.com` which points to `/` but now I am getting SSL issues since I don't have a Let's Encrypt certificate for the subdomain. I tried to obtain one however I keep getting errors `Failed authorization procedure. radio.example.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized`. Am I missing something here or did I get a step too far on this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It sounds like Let's Encrypt can't verify the `.well-known/challenge` URL for HTTP verification. I would suggest creating a second virtual host with the same subdomain (`radio.example.com`) on port 80 with a normal document root and no Apache-based forwarding.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Anaksunaman, however that won't seem to work, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

make your application aware it will be referenced using the radio directory.  I would put it in a radio directory, and configure the application to know it will be ran from a radio directory.  Then the proxypass* will work as expected.

Comment: If I knew a way of telling my application it will be referenced using a directory I would have tried it, however there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: I just checked their git repository, they have an env file example: https://github.com/AzuraCast/AzuraCast/blob/master/azuracast.dev.env in that there is a INIT_BASE_URL, I would change that to the <hostname>/radio location, so every url ends up with that base, then everything should work.

Comment: good call, however that didn't change anything. I still get redirected to false urls, e.g. if I type <hostname>/radio it should redirect me to <hostname>/radio/login however I keep getting redirected to <hostname>/login.